# SQS SNS Subscription between two different Localstack containters

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, localstack

I have two different set of Services. Each service set has a Localstack container running.
Can an SQS created in one Localstack service set subscribe to the SNS created in another Localstack service set ?? How can we handle this scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can, but the containers should be in the same network and use the internal host name (not localhost)
look for network containers config